# Titanium Alloy: Run a function that exists in a require statement

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have the following code:

**index.xml**

```
<Window>
    <View>
        <Require id="foo1" src='foo'>            
    </View>
</Window>
```

**foo.xml**

```
<View>
    <Label>This is from foo</Label>
</View>
```

**foo.js**

```
function doSomething() {
    Ti.API.info('YES!');
}
```

### Question

I want to be able to run the function `doSometing()` in `index.js`. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
$.foo1.doSomething()
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Window>
    <View>
        <Require id="foo1" src='foo'>            
    </View>
</Window>
```

In this code, Require **id** holds the controller of foo.js file, means,

**$.foo1** = **$** in **foo.js**

In order to access any property or method from Require, you can attach that property to any view or just export it like this:

**foo.js**

```
$.doSomething = function () {
    Ti.API.info('YES!');
}
```

**index.js**

```
$.foo1.doSomething();
```

In case of above **@miga's answer**, you need to use this code in **index.js** :

```
// view is the id of topmost view to which you attached the method.
$.foo1.view.doSomething();
```

Comment: Whats the difference between using `exports` compared to setting it directly on `$`

Comment: No difference. $ is equal to that controller and using exports in controller file means the same that you're attaching something to that controller, and Require tag actually gives you the controller level access which is also equal to the **Alloy.createController('foo');**. So $ === controller actually.

Answer (score 1):

foo.xml

```
<View id="view">
    <Label>This is from foo</Label>
</View>
```

foo.js

```
$.view.doSomething = function(){
  Ti.API.info('YES!');
}
```

And then: `$.foo1.view.doSomething();`

**edit:** better

```
exports.doSomething = function(){
  Ti.API.info('YES!');
}
```

to use it without the `.view`!

Comment: I get an error saying, `cannot set property 'doSomething' of undefined. Source $.view.doSomething = function () {`

Comment: Your top solution still has the same error. Your second solutions works however